# C# :- P/invoke signature

Tags: c#, c++, c, pinvoke

I have a dll with following signature in C++. It is working in c++;

```
    void Decompress(unsigned char *in,int in_len,unsigned char * out,
unsigned *o_len,int *e);
```

Description of parameter

1. ***in**  : It is byte array passed to
   function.
2. **in_len** : Length of bytes in first parameter.
3. ***out** : This would be the output as byte array.
4. ***o_len** : No of bytes in third parameter
5. ***e** : Error code returned

How can I call it from c#?

What would be the P/Invoke declaration?

Comment: See also http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joshwil/archive/2005/08/10/450200.aspx , it seems that 32bit and 64bit CLR can do it differently...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
static extern void Decompress(
                byte[] input, 
                int in_len,
                byte[] output, 
                ref int o_len,
                out int e);
```

Comment: How would byte[]output get marshalled to the correct size? Something seems missing here for the marshaller.

Comment: could you tell me how i could call a static function which is part of a class?

QWidget::grabKeyboard ()

Comment: if the class you are refering is a static then you can call it directly classname like

QWidget.grabKeyboard (). if the class is not a static you have to create any one object of that class before calling it (using same syntax).

Comment: An addition: If you need to access many classes located in an object oriented c++ library from managed code, the most efficient way (in terms of effort) is often to go through C++/CLI, a specialized language.